# How to force hibernate not update all entities with same id?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

When I save the `newAddress` using `JpaRepository<Address, AddressID>` save method it updates all references of the method scope, including `oldRegistration`.

Since I wanna execute other actions with the `oldRegistration` data after the `newAddress` is saved It is giving me an unexpected behavior.

```
    Registration registerAddress(String cpf, MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        Registration oldRegistration = registrationService.findById(new CPF(cpf)).orElseThrow(RegistrationNotFound::new);
        Address oldAddress = addressService.findById(oldRegistration.getAddressId()).orElseThrow(AddressNotFoundException::new);

        StorageFile newStorageFile = storageFileService.saveImage(file.getOriginalFilename(), file.getInputStream(), file.getSize());

        Address newAddress = oldAddress.setStorageFile(newStorageFile.getId());
        Registration newRegistration = oldRegistration.registerAddressFile(newAddress.getId());

        addressService.save(newAddress);
        Registration savedRegistration = registrationService.save(newRegistration);

        storageFileService.findById(oldAddress.getStorageFileId()).ifPresent(storageFile -> {
            storageFileService.delete(storageFile);
            storageFileService.removeFromStorageAsync(storageFile);
        });

        return savedRegistration;
    }
```

I'm expecting the `oldAddress` keep all its data.

After `addressService.save(newAddress);` all data from `oldAddress` is setted as the same of the `newAddress`.

How to tell Spring does not update every reference that has the same id?

Comment: The issue is because you are in `Hibernate cache context` then you continue having the same reference. you need to do `flush` after it is saved.

Comment: `flush` is used to synchronize session data with database. When you call `flush()` , the statements are executed in database but it will not committed.  Then you can get new, perhaps this doesn't work then do `flush` and `clear` in order to clear later.

Comment: I tried to create a new AddressID Instance, but the same error occur.

Answer (score 0):

`oldAddress` is a managed entity having the same id as `newAddress`. You need to `EntityManager.detach()` it from the context before saving the `newAddress`.